# Is there any way I can automatically generate BLL classes for a particular database table in c# .NET?

Tags: c#, database, business-logic-layer

I have been writing BLLs for whatever new tables I create in the database and use them in the Data access layer. I was wondering if someone knows if there is an inbuilt option using .NET for generating BLL classes for a table in sql server database.

Comment: If all the BLL objects are the same/similar structure, then perhaps you need a generic base?

Comment: Lots. It entirely depends on what you want your "BLL class" to do. EF is a popular choice, custom T4 code is another, hand-written POCO classes that you map to on a case-by-case basis with Dapper/Automapper yet another, keeping it completely dynamic yet another... I'd say this is too broad.

Comment: [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db#reverse-engineer-your-model) can do this. [Peta Poco](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/wiki/T4-Template-Poco-Builder) has T4 templates. And there are more. Depends on what tech are you using.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want on your objects or the behavior you want to give to them.

You already have Entity Framework as a possibility, that already does something very similar to what you describe.

There is also LLBL Gen Pro (not free, but amazing) that probably does everything you want.

You can also make your own code generator tool combining a template engine (like T4), with queries against your master database, perhaps using MicroORM to simplify DB access.